# xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, node-modules

I was trying to run the node test cases by the command `npm run test:node` but I got the error below. I tried to search this on google but was not able to find anything. I am new to node so don't know much about it. Can anyone please help?

```
marketplace-server@1.0.0 test:node
> find ./server-test -name '*.spec.js' |xargs mocha -R spec
'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "marketplace",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "@cds/core": "^5.5.0",
    "@cds/react": "^5.5.0",
    "@clr/icons": "^4.0.7",
    "@clr/ui": "^4.0.7",
    "@sentry/browser": "^6.13.2",
    "@sentry/react": "^6.13.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.13.2",
    "@vmw/csp-ff-sdk": "^0.8.1",
    "@vmw/csp-header": "^11.1.16",
    "@vmware-react/clarity": "^0.5.22",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.4.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.799.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "echarts": "^4.9.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.16",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "EventEmitter": "^1.0.0",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "intl-tel-input": "^16.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "marketplace-server": "file:..",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.39.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.5.207",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "re-reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-avatar-editor": "11.0.9",
    "react-cookie": "^3.1.2",
    "react-date-picker": "^7.10.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-intl-tel-input-v2": "^1.0.8",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.8.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.5.5",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.10",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-s3": "^1.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.2",
    "react-select": "^3.1.1",
    "react-slick": "0.27.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "react-youtube": "^7.13.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.0",
    "socket.io-client-cookies-headers": "^0.4.2",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.8.0",
    "typeface-metropolis": "0.0.74",
    "universal-cookie": "^3.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "valid-url": "^1.0.9",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-core": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-routing": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-streams": "^5.1.3",
    "xss": "^1.0.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/main.*",
    "start": "react-scripts start --max-http-header-size=80000",
    "start-dev": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=dev react-scripts start",
    "start-local": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=local REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=local react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build-env": "cross-env ENV=$ENV node copyEnvConfig && CI=false npm run build",
    "build-env:local": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=local REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=local CI=false npm run build",
    "build-env:devel": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=dev CI=false npm run build",
    "build-env:devqa": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=devqa CI=false npm run build",
    "build-env:devint": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=devint CI=false npm run build",
    "build-env:staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=staging CI=false npm run build",
    "build-env:production": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=prod REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=production CI=false npm run build",
    "styleguide": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=local REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=local styleguidist --port 9000 server",
    "build-styleguide:local": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=local REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=local styleguidist build",
    "build-styleguide:devel": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=dev styleguidist build",
    "build-styleguide:staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=staging styleguidist build",
    "build-styleguide:production": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=prod REACT_APP_CONFIG_ENV=production styleguidist build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "react-styleguidist": "11.1.6",
    "sass": "^1.48.0",
    "yamljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "terser": "4.8.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I couldn't find any package named xargs. Can anyone please help?

Comment: most likely, you need to install xargs as per your linux distro.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. And there is no dependency/package named xargs.